# Eliminar un objeto creado c#

Tags: c#, poo

Con mi `btnAgregar` inserto objetos a mi clase `Trabajador`, como podría poner mi `btnEliminar` para dar de baja un objeto conociendo solo su nomina?? Espero que mi pregunta se haya entendido, gracias!

```
public class Form11
{
    String nomina;
    public List<Trabajador> trabajadores = new List<Trabajador>();
    Trabajador trabajador;
    private void btnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        trabajador = new Trabajador("Pedro", "1234");
        trabajadores.Add(trabajador);    
    }

    private void btnElimar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        nomina;
    }

    public class Trabajador
    {
        public String nombre1, nomina1;
        public Trabajador(String Nombre, String Nomina)
        {
            nombre1 = Nombre;
            nomina1 = Nomina;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puede utilizar `RemoveAll` de linq.

```
private void btnElimar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    trabajadores.RemoveAll(c => c.nomina1== nomina);
}
```

Si solo necesitas eliminar la primera coincidencia de los item de la lista, entonces puede utilizar `Remove` o `RemoveAt`.

> [RemoveAll](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=netframework-4.7.2): Quita todos los elementos que cumplen las condiciones
>   definidas por el predicado especificado.
>
> [Remove](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=netframework-4.7.2): Quita la primera aparición de un objeto específico de la
>   interfaz List.
>
> [RemoveAt](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeat?view=netframework-4.7.2): Quita el elemento situado en el índice especificado de
>   List.

Answer (score 4):

Primero algunas correcciones en el codigo que publicas, como por ejemplo:

- No utilices la instancia global del `trabajador` para agregar items en una lista, ya que en cada iteracion estaras pisando la instancia anterior quedando todos los items de la lista referenciando al mismo trabajador. Recurda los `objetos` se vinculan por `referencia` a un puntero en memoria.
- Usar propiedades y no variables publicas para definir una entidad
- La clase se define por fuera del `form` nivel de `namespace`

Por ejemplo usando `linq` puede ver si existe un trabajador buscandolo en la coleccion por su propiedad y removerlo

```
 public class Form11
 {

    private List<Trabajador> trabajadores = new List<Trabajador>();

    private void btnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Trabajador trabajador = new Trabajador("Pedro", "1234");
        trabajadores.Add(trabajador);    
    }

    private void btnElimar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var trabajador = trabajadores.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Nomina = nomina);

        if(trabajador != null)
        {
            trabajadores.Remove(trabajador);
        }
    }


}


public class Trabajador
{
    public Trabajador(string nombre, string nomina)
    {
        this.Nombre = nombre;
        this.Nomina1 = nomina;
    }

    public string Nombre {get;set;}
    public string Nomina {get;set;}
}
```

[List.Remove(T) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=netframework-4.5)